# float right not working

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a chat system, it worked perfectly fine on my local but appears that I've missed some CSS or HTML somewhere? I've tried comparing my files & can't see anything missing.

Firstly, here's the JS fiddle I did : https://jsfiddle.net/xefhrj73/1/

As you can see the first 2 messages appear correct, although on the `float:left` elements, the avatar is below the div instead of to the side, which I'm guessing is breaking the rest of my `float:right` elements continuing from it?

I tried adding `clear:inherit` which worked in putting the avatar to the left, but breaks the formatting between messages

```css
 
.chat-left .chat-avatar {
    float: left;
}
.chat-left .chat-body {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.chat-left .chat-content {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}
.chat-avatar .avatar {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.chat-avatar .avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1000px;
}
.chat-avatar .avatar {
    width: 30px;
}
.chat-avatar {
    float: right;
}
.chat-body {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 30px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.chat-content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff5722;
    border-radius: .286rem;
    max-width: 400px;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chat-content p{
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat chat-right ">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
  <a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-body">
  <div class="chat-content">
     <p>Hey I&#039;d like more information regarding this property!</p>
     <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 16:06:39"> 1 hour ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
   <p>test</p>
   <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:24:22"> 23 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="chat chat-left ">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
  <a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="left" title="Default">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88b87698be0bc461f3cacf1f080929d5.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Default's Avatar">
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hi</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:34:32"> 13 minutes ago</time>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
   <p>hey</p>
   <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:34:58"> 13 minutes ago</time>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="chat chat-right ">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
  <a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hey</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:13"> 12 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
   <p>hi hi hi</p>
   <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:22"> 11 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="chat chat-left ">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
  <a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="left" title="Default">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88b87698be0bc461f3cacf1f080929d5.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Default's Avatar">
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hi hi hi hi</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:55"> 11 minutes ago</time>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
   <p>lol from creator</p>
   <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:37:55"> 10 minutes ago</time>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="chat chat-right ">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
  <a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>lol from buyer</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:38:45"> 9 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. The code must be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `clearfix` div before starting every left-chat/right-chat div
Also your code had some unwanted closing divs. Try to format your code alsways to see such things clearly.

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.chat-left {
   display: flex;
}
```

```css
.chat-left .chat-avatar {
  float: left;
}

.chat-left .chat-body {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.chat-left .chat-content {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.chat-avatar .avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.chat-avatar .avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}

.chat-avatar .avatar {
  width: 30px;
}

.chat-avatar {
  float: right;
}

.chat-body {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 30px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff5722;
  border-radius: .286rem;
  max-width: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.chat-content p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.chat-left {
  display: flex;
}

.chat-right>div {}
```

```html
<div class="chat chat-right ">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
<a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
            </a>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-body">
<div class="chat-content">
  <p>Hey I&#039;d like more information regarding this property!</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 16:06:39"> 1 hour ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
<p>test</p>
<time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:24:22"> 23 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
  </div>
</div>





<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="chat chat-left ">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
<a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="left" title="Default">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88b87698be0bc461f3cacf1f080929d5.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Default's Avatar">
            </a>
  </div>
  <div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hi</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:34:32"> 13 minutes ago</time>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hey</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:34:58"> 13 minutes ago</time>
</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="chat chat-right ">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
<a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
            </a>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-body">
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hey</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:13"> 12 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hi hi hi</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:22"> 11 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="chat chat-left ">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
<a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="left" title="Default">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88b87698be0bc461f3cacf1f080929d5.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Default's Avatar">
            </a>
  </div>
  <div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>hi hi hi hi</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:36:55"> 11 minutes ago</time>
</div>
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>lol from creator</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:37:55"> 10 minutes ago</time>
</div>
  </div>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="chat chat-right ">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
<a class="avatar" data-toggle="tooltip" href="" data-placement="right" title="Backend">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30aa172009d1e4e569d31a54899af0ee.jpg?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Backend's Avatar">
            </a>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-body">
<div class="chat-content" style="margin-right:50px;">
  <p>lol from buyer</p>
  <time class="chat-time" datetime="2018-06-11 17:38:45"> 9 minutes ago <i class="fa fa-check m-l-5 text-read" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Read"></i></time>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xefhrj73/16/)

Comment: Thanks for trying but appears the avatar on the left doesn't align with the `chat-content` like it does on the first 2 chat boxes

Comment: I didnt know that you wanted it aligned. will try to fix it ass well

Comment: Thankyou, I'm basically trying to get the full chat layout the same as the first 1/2 messages but somethings gone wrong somewhere

Comment: Fixed all your issues. Please check now. You had missed  <div class="chat-body"> around right chat divs